# Netlogo SET expected 2 inputs

Tags: netlogo

I am new to NetLogo but I have worked on 4 Projects of mine so far and I've never run into this error, I am trying to set up a monitor that counts ticks as money and placing a blue patch should "cost" 100 units of money and removing one patch and letting it turns back to its first state should give me 50 units of money back, the monitor and turning the patches blue works but the money system just doesn't, so I am not sure where the mistake is.
This is the Code I am working on:

````
 let Bank count (patches with [pcolor = blue])
 if (pcolor = blue) [
 if (Bank = Bank + 1) [
   set money = money - 100
    ]][ if(Bank = Bank - 1) [
      set money = money + 50]
]]

end```
````

Comment: In NetLogo `=` is just for checking equality for a conditional, like `if`.  To set a variable's value, you do not use `=` at all you just `set var-name value`.  So `set money money - 100` or `set money money + 50`.  See the docs for `set` for more info: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#set

Comment: Netlogo set doesnt use `=` just use `set money money - 100`. But first of all how can the second if statement `if (Bank = Bank + 1) ` be true at all?

Comment: @Jasper Thanks a lot! I don't get the error message anymore, sadly I have run into different problems after I fixed this one.